# ModuleNotFoundError when working with multiple folders

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I got a question/problem related to how to use **init**.py file for a project im working on. Im trying to run train_pipeline.py, which is located at
`packages/cnn_modality_clf/cnn_modality_clf/train_pipeline.py`
This file uses scripts that are located in the same folder, and also files that are within folders.

My imports (within train_pipeline.py

```
from cnn_modality_clf.pipeline import pipe
from cnn_modality_clf.config import config
from cnn_modality_clf.preprocessing import data_management as dm 
from cnn_modality_clf.preprocessing import preprocessors as pp
```

However, when I run this train_pipeline file, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named cnn_modality_clf` and the error is on `from cnn_modality_clf.pipeline import pipe`

I have worked on previous projects (not that many) where using the **init**.py file will solved this issue. However, I have added this file into every folder. But that doesnt seem to work out.

My project structure looks like this:

[image]

I want to be able to use the python files that are within the same path, or that are within a folder (cnn.modality_clf.pipeline import pipe)

*Im using anaconda environment, and im using python 3.7.0

Any suggestions on how to overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try appending the folder path to `sys.path` ?

Comment: The main script (the one you use to start) should be at the root location of the package structure (here: `packages/cnn_modality_clf`). Alternatively use the suggested `sys.path`.

Comment: @MichaelButscher  can you guys expand a little bit more on this?

Comment: Absolute imports must be actually relative to one of the root directories listed in "sys.path". The directory of the main script is automatically added to "sys.path".

Comment: @MichaelButscher thanks! I was able to figure it out. Thank you so much!